# What is the point of having an equal sign after an argument description

Tags: python, arguments

I have seen in python builtin functions that there is an equal sign after argument descriptions. For example ->

```py
 def print(
        *values: object, sep: Optional[Text] = ..., end: Optional[Text] = ..., file: Optional[_Writer] = ..., flush: bool = ...
    ) -> None: ...
```

What is the point of having `sep: OptionalText = ...`?

Comment: That looks more like documentation, showing you that the `sep` parameter *has* a default value without bothering to show what that default is.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `...` is a valid Python literal, a synonym for `Ellipsis` which is the sole value of the class `ellipsis`, but that interpretation doesn't fit with the type hints shown.